# R - Importing a text file which includes information in header lines above the main data table

Tags: r, dataframe, text, import

I'd like to import a text file which contains a table of results with two 'header' lines of text above it. The contents of the header lines needs to be included as extra columns in the resulting data.frame.

In the following example text file, the Region and Month lines are the header lines, and the remainder of the file is the results table.

```
Region  South Africa
Month   July
Sepal.Length    Sepal.Width Petal.Length    Petal.Width Species
1   5.1 3.5 1.4 0.2 setosa
2   4.9 3   1.4 0.2 setosa
3   4.7 3.2 1.3 0.2 setosa
```

needs to become a data.frame which includes columns for Region and Month:

```
wanted.df<-structure(list(Sepal.Length = c(1, 2, 3), Sepal.Width = c(5.1, 
4.9, 4.7), Petal.Length = c(3.5, 3, 3.2), Petal.Width = c(1.4, 
1.4, 1.3), Species = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2), Region = c("South Africa", 
"South Africa", "South Africa"), Month = c("July", "July", "July"
)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I've managed to do it by creating two data.frames, one containing the header info, the second containing the result table and then merging them, but this seems to me a bit ungainly:

```
#Create data frame from first two lines of text (the header)
header <- scan('example.txt', nlines = 2, what = character(),sep = "\n")
header.df<-data.frame((sapply(header,function(x){str_split(x, "\t")})),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
colnames(header.df) <- as.character(header.df[1,])
header.df<-header.df[-1,]

#Create data frame from first remainder of the file which contains the results table  
results.df<-read_tsv('example.txt',col_names = T,skip=2)

#helper column added to both data frames for merging
results.df$helper.col<- "match"
header.df$helper.col<-"match"
df.example<-inner_join(results.df,header.df, by = "helper.col", copy = FALSE)
wanted.df<-select(df.example,-helper.col)
```

Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: How do you know "South Africa" is one word and not separate words? Or do you know there is always going to be only two columns in header ?

Comment: @RonakShah - It seems to be a tab separated file (OP uses `read_tsv()` and splits the header info on `\t`).

Comment: @RonakShah, yes, it is a tab separated file (and the number of columns in the header is fixed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming @H 1's comment is correct that it is a tab-separated file. We can do

```
df1 <- read.table('example.txt', nrows = 2, sep = "\t")
df2 <- data.frame(matrix(df1$V2, ncol = nrow(df1), dimnames = list(NULL, df1$V1)))
df3 <- read.table(text = 'example.txt', skip = 2, header = TRUE)
cbind(df3, df2)

#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species       Region Month
#1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa South Africa  July
#2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa South Africa  July
#3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa South Africa  July
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do it in this way:

```
header <- readLines('file.txt', n = 2)
header <- stringi::stri_split_regex(header, '\\W+', n = 2)

dat <- read.table('file.txt', skip = 2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
for(i in header){ dat[ i[1] ] <- i[2] }

# > dat
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species       Region Month
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa South Africa  July
# 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa South Africa  July
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa South Africa  July
```